# Do subsequent arguments override previous from linux kernel command line, or vice versa?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-parameters

This was prompted by [another question elsewhere](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/136076/how-to-edit-coherent-pool-setting-via-cmdline-txt), which after digging into briefly a quick online search ("linux kernel command line override priority" and some variations) turned up absolutely nothing.

The issue is that `/proc/cmdline` indicates a parameter has been included twice with different values.  **My question is NOT about why that is or how it can happen**, it's which one has precedence.  In other words, given this as a commandline:

```
foo=12 console=tty1 foo=16
```

If `foo` is a setting which cannot meaningfully have two values, is there any convention for which one applies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure it’s documented explicitly in the kernel, but [the x86-specific boot command-line parsing](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.7/source/arch/x86/boot/cmdline.c#L21) includes this comment:

> Find a non-boolean option, that is, "option=argument".  In accordance
> with standard Linux practice, if this option is repeated, this returns
> the last instance on the command line.

This allows users to add settings to the end of their command-line without caring about any preceding values in the command-line.

Looking at [the generic parsing code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.7/source/kernel/params.c#L161) confirms this: parameters are read one after another, and any value set by a duplicated parameter is overwritten by the last instance.

In your example, `foo=16` wins.

Note that tools which parse `/proc/cmdline` have their own behaviour and may not follow the kernel convention.