# The precedence of kernel module options: kernel boot parameters vs. modeprobe.d?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, modprobe

If I have `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` in kernel parameter and `options nvidia-drm modeset=0` in `modeprobe.d`. Then which value is in use?

If I have multiple `nvidia-drm.modeset` in kernel parameter, then which one is going to be used the first one or the last one?

I am asking this because the rpmfusion guys decide to add `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to `/etc/default/grub` I need it to be off. But it seems every time I reinstall the driver, it keep adding this value to the default grub configuration. I want to override this without always calling grubby or manually changing the default grub after driver installation.

After testing this on a VM, I think I figured it out:

1. boot parameters always override the modprobe.d
2. the last parameter always win

Comment: Please report it as a bug to https://bugzilla.rpmfusion.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, when multiple conflicting arguments are present:

- [the last value set wins](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689802/86440) (so one can always override a value on the generated kernel command-line by adding a value at the end)
- the kernel command-line wins over settings stored in files (so one can always recover a system with incorrect settings in its configuration files).